# My read_lines() function, when called does not run as expected. Is there a way to fix my current implementation?

Tags: c, macos, stdout

Oddly, the printf statement on line 30 does not run either. When I ran the lldb debugger, all the printf statement and the while loop in read_lines() were executed according to the arrow indicator but without any output. However, when the code in the read_lines() function is put in place of the read_lines() (line 11) function call, it ran as expected with output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // prototyped my functions
    void open_stream();
    void read_lines();

    open_stream(); // runs as expected
    read_lines(); // does not run as expected

    return 0;
}
// this function runs as expected
void open_stream() {
    printf("Executes\n");
    FILE *fp;

    fp = freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout);

    printf("This text is redirected to file.txt.\n");
    printf("This is also redirected.\n");

    fclose(fp);
}
// this function doesn't run as expected
void read_lines()
{
    printf("Does not execute\n"); // doesn't print
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
       perror("Error in opening file.");
    }

    while(1) {
       c = fgetc(fp); // doesn't seem to work
       if( feof(fp) ) {
          break ;
       }
       printf("%c", c); // nothing gets printed
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

file.txt:

```
This text is redirected to file.txt.
This is also redirected.
```

Expected Output:

```
$ ./file_scratch
Executes   
Does not execute
This text is redirected to file.txt.
This is also redirected.
```

Actual output:

```
$ ./file_scratch
Executes
```

Additional info:
It seems that the open_stream() and read_lines() functions interfere with each other. I am able to run read_lines() (provided I kept file.txt) when I comment out open_stream(). My guess is, is that I did not handle/close freopen() correctly and perhaps stdout also became affected. I tried different things to try to handle this with no avail. What am I missing? I know I could just simply use fopen(), fprintf(), and etc. But is there a correct implementation of what I am trying to do here?

Comment: You closed the output file, so the program no longer has a `stdout` for `printf` to use.

Comment: In the future, when you post code, please remove the line numbers.

Comment: Why do you expect "This text is redirected to file.txt" to appear in the terminal instead of in the file?

Comment: Have you looked in `file.txt` to see what's there?

Comment: Try `printf("Does not execute\n");` --> `fprintf(stderr, "Does not execute\n");` to still get some output.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Sorry about that, I edited out the line numbers

Comment: @WilliamPursell I posted the conents of file.txt.
I expected printf("%c", c); to print out the contents of the file.

Comment: `freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout);` changes stdout to point to the file so everything you print after that goes to the file for the entire rest of the program - but then you close the file and there there is no way to output anything.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah In my open_stream() function I commented out close(fp); to avoid closing stdout. After doing so, "Does not execute" gets added to the file as well. Is there a way to switch stdout back to normal and print out the contents of the file in this program after using freopen() ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819575/c-freopen-descriptor-close-manually-leave-opened) stdout needs to be reopened if a fclose() is called on the file it is pointing to. It was stated that it is better practice to close the filehandle (stdout) with `fclose(stdout);` rather than the file pointer. Then to reopen the filehandle with `freopen("/dev/tty", "a", stdout);` to return to the normal functionality of stdout. Further helpful information related to this topic can be found [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // prototyped my functions
    void open_stream();
    void read_lines();

    open_stream(); // now runs as expected
    read_lines(); // now runs as expected as well

    return 0;
}
// this function runs as expected
void open_stream() {
    printf("Executes\n");
    FILE *fp;

    fp = freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout);

    printf("This text is redirected to file.txt.\n");
    printf("This is also redirected.\n");

    fclose(stdout); // using this instead of fclose(fp);
    freopen("/dev/tty", "a", stdout); // reopening stdout after closing it 
}
// this function now runs as expected
void read_lines()
{
    printf("Executes this time\n"); // now it prints
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
       perror("Error in opening file.");
    }

    while(1) {
       c = fgetc(fp); // now it works
       if( feof(fp) ) {
          break ;
       }
       printf("%c", c); // gets printed now
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Output:

```
Executes
Executes this time
This text is redirected to file.txt.
This is also redirected.
```